# Export odi/odsi to text files for source control

Tags: sql, etl

ODI is mandatory at work but any changes made to SQL
are stored internally

I wish to programmatically pull out all SQL from
ODI store it in source control and then I can diff 
and at least use half decent code reviews (worrying about who changed what 
is far less of a problem than wondering if people are remembering
all their changes

So - how can I programmatically pull out Sql from ODI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit www.odietamo.org.uk

Thats how we solved it